# Polymer, how to change :host styling of an element

Tags: polymer

I want to change the styling of paper-icon-buttons, specifically the padding that is defined on paper-icon-button via :host. However, I think this is not possible according to the specs?

So in order to change the styling, one would have to actually change the Polymer element itself, right? Which is a problem though if I want to get updates of the element via bower. Is there a way to change the :host styling with CSS outside of the Polymer element? This is not working.

```
paper-icon-button:host {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Take a look and see if it helps https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html%23style-fromoutside

Answer (score 0):

You can specify styling directly on an instance of the element or with css on the element's name - http://jsbin.com/mohifu/3/edit

Comment: I should have used a different example, sorry. This doesn't seem to be working for me in a core-scaffold on a core-icon-button. The CSS always gets overwritten by Polymer. Also doesn't work if I add !important.

Answer (score -1):

Just apply the css directly to element

```
paper-icon-button{
    padding: 4px;
}
```